# Angular 6: can't display values fetching localStorage

Tags: arrays, angular, local-storage

I can save, read or update data with localstorage. But im trying to use a Model to display all users (id and userName) with the directive *ngFor. But I get the error: "Only arrays and iterables are allowed". I'm missing something; can someone help me out?

The simple model:

```
export interface User {
  id:number;
  userName:string;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="test" >
      <button (click)="saveUser(test)" class=" btn btn-danger">SAVE</button>
<div>
  <button (click)="readUser(test)" class=" btn btn-danger">Read</button>
</div>
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let user of test">
    <li>{{user.id}}</li>
    <li>{{user.userName}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the component class:

```
export class Testing implements OnInit {

  test: User[]=[];

  constructor() { }

  saveUser(user:string){

    localStorage.setItem('userName', JSON.stringify(user));

    console.log(user)
  }

  readUser(){
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')) 
  }
```

Comment: anyone, please?

Comment: You're mapping an input (text, so a string) to an array. So when you type characters into the input, the array gets overwritten by the corresponding string and it's no longer an array, making `*ngFor` unable to iterate over it. What exactly is that input supposed to do? Add a user to the array?

Comment: yes, I want to save as many users as possible, then display them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your input a name such as `#userInput` and pass its value to `saveUser` with:

`<button (click)="saveUser(userInput.value)" ...>`

`saveUser` must also add the user to your `test` (should be `users`) array.

**Script**

```
export class Testing {
  private currentId = 0;
  test: User[] = [];

  saveUser(userName: string) {
    this.test.push({id: ++this.currentId, userName})
    // ...
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<input #userInput class="form-control">
  <button (click)="saveUser(userInput.value)" class=" btn btn-danger">SAVE</button>
<div>
  <button (click)="readUser(test)" class=" btn btn-danger">Read</button>
</div>
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let user of test">
    <li>{{user.id}}</li>
    <li>{{user.userName}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enew6o)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for the explanation and the stackBlitz. Greetings, Jeto

Answer (score 1):

You can have following ts file:

```
   test = '';
  _id = 0;
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  saveUser(user: string) {
    this.users.push({id: this._id++, userName: this.test});

    localStorage.setItem('userName', JSON.stringify(this.users));

    console.log(user);
  }

  readUser() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')));
  }
```

and the following template(html) file.

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="test" >
      <button (click)="saveUser(test)" class=" btn btn-danger">SAVE</button>
<div>
  <button (click)="readUser(test)" class=" btn btn-danger">Read</button>
</div>
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let user of users">
    <li>{{user.id}}</li>
    <li>{{user.userName}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Notice that you cannot treat `test` as an array. Because `test` is bound with `input` tag and is a string not array.

In order to treat something as array for *ngFor introduce another property called `users` as shown in the code.